# splitting scrollview so it strectch for half the screen but it's ignoring the layout weight

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a vertical scroll view that shows up on the top half of the screen, the bottom half will have a few buttons.

I have a vertical linear layout with two vertical linear layouts inside of it (the top one containing the scrollview) and have set each of the two linear layouts to have a layout weight of 1 but the scroll view stretches past half the page regardless.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b_whitetrans4">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/settingtext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Oddly enough the scrollview doesn't stretch all the way to show all the content but it's definitely more than half the screen. This is what happens:
https://www.screencast.com/t/VPHJwPhpLyb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using weight in Linear Layouts, it is advisable to use height(if orientation is vertical) and width(if orientation is horizontal)=0dp.
In your case, its vertical.
Try doing that.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/b_whitetrans4">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settingtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. works perfectly like this, thank you!

Comment: Glad this helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Set the top LinearLayout's height to `match_parent` and remove the `layout_weight` attribute on the lower one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting the parent of the layouts as a RelativeLayout, then using alignParentTop/alignParentBottom instead of layout_weight on your LinearLayouts

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative